# git pull зависает на стадии Unpacking objects

Tags: git

Достаточно долгое время все работало хорошо, однако после последнего пуша в bare-репозиторий на сервере, перестал работать git pull локально везде:

Unpacking objects:  32% (29/90)

Зависает именно на этой цифре. Передача происходит по ssh-протоколу. В чем может быть проблема? Достигнут какой-то лимит какого-нибудь буфера?

Comment: а если попробовать склонировать репозиторий в другую папку, работает?

Comment: @KoVadim, пытался, работает, но очень медленно. Там за 5 минут буквально несколько процентов склонировалось (цифру не запомнил)

Comment: как безумный вариант - сыпиться диск. Или антивирус/фаервол решили проверить ваш репозиторий.

Comment: @KoVadim вариантов много ) единственное что заметил - пинг соединения с сервером увеличился.

Comment: Встречаю такое когда проблемы с сетью, например, канал забит

Comment: @TheSpbra1n так и оказалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема в том, что комит оказался слишком большим, а скорость соединения на сервере была низкой. перезагрузил сервер, и комит спулился. правда, не быстро.

Comment: Раз это решение, отметьте его галочкой. Так принято на SO.